# Why has the number not been found by regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract string from html code.
I have a regexp. After I open file (or after I make "get" request) I need to find pattern.

So, I have an html code and I want to find such string:

`<input type="hidden" name="qid" ... anything is possible bla="blabla" ... value="8">`

I want to find the string **qid**, then find after it the string **value="435345"** and extract 435345.

Now I am just trying to find this string (I have already done it) and then I will make a replacement (I am going to do it), but this code couldn't find the pattern. What is wrong?

```
open(URLS_OUT, $foundResults);
@lines = <URLS_OUT>;
$content = join('', @lines);

$content =~ /<qid\"\s*value=[^>][0-9]+/;
print 'Yes'.$1.'\n';

close(URLS_OUT);
```

or this code:

```
my $content = $response->content(); 

while ($content =~ /<qid\"\s*value=[^>][0-9]+/g)
    {
        print 'Yes'.$1.'\n';
    }
```

I have checked that the file is not empty and it is opened correctly (I have printed it out), but I the program can't find pattern. What is wrong? I have checked the regular expression using this cite (and some others): http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
It shows that the regular expression is correct and finds what I need.

Comment: How does the html tag **really** look like? Like this? `<qid" value=12345`? or is it `<qid value="12345"`. Or different?

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" value="8">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea how:

```
$content =~ /<qid\"\s*value=[^>][0-9]+/;
```

works is wrong. Please study [basic Regex usage in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

BTW: you shouldn't parse HTML by regex. There are a lot [examples on the web and on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) how to do that correctly. Look it up!

---

For learning purpose, your regex would look like this (according to your comment):

```
my $content = q{
 <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" bla="blabla" value="8">
 <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" bla="blabla" value="98">
 <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" bla="blabla" value="788">
 <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" bla="blabla" value="128">
 <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" bla="blabla" value="8123">
};
my $regex = qr{ name=     # find the attribute 'name'
                "qid"     # with a content of "quid"
                .+?       # now search along until the next 'value'
                value=    # the following attribute 'value' 
                "(\d+)    # find the number and capture it
              }x;   ## allow the regex to be formatted   

while( $content =~ /$regex/g ) { # /g - search along
   print "Yes $1 \n"
}
```

---

After you got this working, please study how to read the content with an [HTML-Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm).

Comment: thanks, I know that I should use HTML::Parser but for it's faster to use regexp. I need to do the work as faster as I could, moreover, I have a lot of texts (html, ASCII text, xml). That is why I use regexp.

Comment: @user565447 - after 'discovering' your 'lost' tag from your original post, I updated my answer again (by `.+?`). Can you explain in detail what the regex does?

Answer (score 3):

Update your regex like this:

```
/<qid\"\s*value=([^>][0-9]+)/
```

That is, add the "(" and ")" to capture the data in `$1`

Answer (score 3):

Use [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm) to cope with messy real-world HTML.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;

sub start {
  my($attr,$attrseq) = @_;
  while (defined(my $name = shift @$attrseq)) {  # first ...="qid"
    last if $attr->{$name} eq "qid";
  }
  while (defined(my $name = shift @$attrseq)) {  # then value="<num>"
    if ($name eq "value" && $attr->{$name} =~ /\A[0-9]+\z/) {
      print "Yes", $attr->{$name}, "\n";
    }
  }
}

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
  api_version => 3,
  start_h => [\&start, "attr, attrseq"],
);
$p->parse_file(*DATA);

__DATA__
<input type="hidden" name="qid" value="8">
<input type="hidden" name="qidx" value="000000">
<foo type="hidden" name="qid" value="9">
<foo type="hidden" name="qid" value="000000x">
<foo type="hidden" name="QID" value="000000">
<bar type="hidden" NAME="qid" value="10">
<baz type="hidden" name="qid" VALUE="11">
<quux type="hidden" NAME="qid" VALUE="12">
```

Output:

```
Yes8
Yes9
Yes10
Yes11
Yes12
```

Answer (score 2):

For `$1` to contain a value, you need to use a [Capture Group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups). Try:

```
$content =~ /<qid\"\s*value=([^>][0-9]+)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sample you give, your regular expression should look something like this:

```
$content =~ m{
               \"       # match a double quote
               qid      # match the string: qid
               \"       # match a double quote
               [^>]*    # match anything but the closing >
               value    # match the string: value
               \=       # match an equal sign
               \"       # match a double quote
               (\d+)    # capture a string of digits
               \"       # match a double quote
             }msx;
```

Comment: The `"`-quote is not a regex special char. Escaping it doesn't help ;-). The equal `=` isn't either.

Comment: It doesn't hurt either. In Perl's regular expressions, special meta-characters are non-alphanumerics and backslash-escaped alphanumerics. All non-meta-characters are backslash-escaped non-alphanumerics and alphanumerics. If you get into the habit of backslashing non-alphanumerics when you mean them literally, then you will avoid errors.